# Start one windows form application from another windows form application in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to Windows Form applications in C# and i am currently stuck and in need of a bit of help.

Lets say, i currently have one windows form application *App1* running. Upon the occurrence of a specific event in *App1*, lets say a `button_click`, another windows form application *App2* should start. Also *App2* must take a few common values from *App1* like lets say a date value and act upon this date and perform some other operations.

is this fundamentally possible and if so how can it be achieved ?

Thanks for the help..

Comment: Search for Process.Start method.

Comment: Nothing is impossible, but just don't do this.  You can also open another window instead.  If you have to then you'll need to serialize the data into a file so the other process can read it.